# Plotting date data with pcolor

Tags: matplotlib

I have data like this:

```
dates = ['1874-05-02', '1874-05-03', '1874-05-04', 
         '1874-05-05', '1874-05-06','1874-05-07']
data1 = ['-7.000', '7.000', '2.000', '11.600', '13.500', '-13.500']
data2 = ['0.000', '25.000', '0.000', '75.000', '12.000', '22.000']
```

and I need to draw a diagram where dates are on x-axis and data1 on y-axis. Data2 is needed to draw dots in diagram and they should all be in differend colours corresponding their values. So how can I do this with pcolor or pcolormesh?

Here is an example-code I found from http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/pcolor_demo.html and I was wondering could I get anything like this out with my data? Here is another link to demonstrate what I'm supposed to do: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/47527320/diagram.jpg. Can I get a diagram like this with pcolor?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

dx, dy = 0.15, 0.05

y, x = np.mgrid[slice(-3, 3 + dy, dy),slice(-3, 3 + dx, dx)]
z = (1 - x / 2. + x ** 5 + y ** 3) * np.exp(-x ** 2 - y ** 2)
z = z[:-1, :-1]
z_min, z_max = -np.abs(z).max(), np.abs(z).max()



plt.subplot(2, 2, 1)
plt.pcolor(x, y, z, cmap='RdBu', vmin=z_min, vmax=z_max)
plt.title('pcolor')
plt.axis([x.min(), x.max(), y.min(), y.max()])
plt.colorbar()

plt.show()
```

Comment: I found this from matplotlib.org/ and it basically does exactly what I would like to do. I just dont have any idea where to put my data in this code to get out similar diagram whit the numbers I want.

Comment: (http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/pcolor_demo.html)    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

dx, dy = 0.15, 0.05


y, x = np.mgrid[slice(-3, 3 + dy, dy),
                slice(-3, 3 + dx, dx)]
z = (1 - x / 2. + x ** 5 + y ** 3) * np.exp(-x ** 2 - y ** 2)

z = z[:-1, :-1]
z_min, z_max = -np.abs(z).max(), np.abs(z).max()



plt.subplot(2, 2, 1)
plt.pcolor(x, y, z, cmap='RdBu', vmin=z_min, vmax=z_max)
plt.title('pcolor')

plt.axis([x.min(), x.max(), y.min(), y.max()])
plt.colorbar()

plt.show()

Comment: I don't see any connection between the example plot link you posted and what you describe in your question (no dates, no colored dots).  Please check the link, find a more apt example, or explain the connection.

Comment: Could you please edit your post to include the code?

Comment: You provide only three 1D series, for `pcolor(mesh)` you need a three 2D arrays for x,y, and z values. And even then i doubt if you want to use `pcolor`.

Comment: if I need 2D arrays, can I combine my data somehow to create 2D arrays for x,y and z? Like using numpy or something?

Comment: Closed?  OP list working code, and asks a specific question (can I get a diagram like this using pcolor?).  imho, this shouldn't have been closed.  The answer, btw, is "no", but that using scatter plot will work.  Seems perfect for SO, or at least good enough.

Answer (score 2):

A [scatter plot](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.scatter) will give what you describe.

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as plt
import datetime
dt = datetime.datetime

dates = [dt(1874,05,02), dt(1874,05,03), dt(1874,05,04), dt(1874,05,05), dt(1874,05,06),dt(1874,05,07)] 
data1 = [-7.000, 7.000, 2.000, 11.600, 13.500, -13.500]
data2 = [0.000, 25.000, 0.000, 75.000, 12.000, 22.000]

plt.scatter(dates, data1, c=data2, s=400)

plt.show()
```

[image]

There was some discussion in the comments about needing 2D data, but I think that was due to lack of clarity of what you were looking for.  The types of plots in your mpl example link  and your sketch are completely different in nature.  Take a look through the mpl [gallery page](http://matplotlib.org/gallery.html) and you'll see that the ones like your sketch (and that also match the structure of your data well) are using a scatter plot.

There are lots of options here for how to handle the dates and colors, but this should get you started.